# Обособление имён собственных

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, как обособляются имена (и обособляются ли) в данных предложениях?
*Она застала его во время интимной близости с женой лучшего друга Татьяной.
У вас есть общий ребенок Олег, ему 12 лет.*

Интересует, ставится ли запятая перед именем? Или тире? Или ничего не ставится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имя собственное может и обособляться, и не обособляться. Это зависит от того, есть ли оттенок уточнения во фразе. Правило:

> Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его): Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.); Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении.

Обособляют обычно при помощи запятой. Тире обозначает длинную интонационную паузу. Есть ли она, когда речь идёт о художественном тексте, решает автор. Но тире ставят редко.

В Ваших примерах острой нужды в запятых нет, хотя автор этого текста имеет право подчеркнуть интонацию при помощи знаков препинания. Ошибкой это считаться не будет.