# Обособление имени собственного

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

*Этот царь ушёл с войсками, а царством осталась править дочь его Марфа-царевна.*

Вопрос кажется простым и не стоящим внимания, но не даёт покоя. При наборе темы вопроса предлагается множество похожих, например "[Обособление имён собственных](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458986/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)".

Параграф Розенталя "[Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)" читал неоднократно:

> 6. Собственное имя лица <...> выступает в роли **обособленного** приложения, если поясняет либо уточняет нарицательное существительное.

Далее в примечании:

> Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении.

И есть такой пример:

> *Он сына моего, **Борьку**, напомнил* (есть только <...> один сын; если бы было несколько, то при выражении той же мысли собственное имя не следовало бы обособлять).

**Вопрос**

У царя ентого есть только одна дочь — Марфушенька-душенька. Так что ж получается, нужно ставить запятую? Или всё же возможны оба варианта в зависимости от интонации и воли (замысла) автора? Вот этот пример с Борькой и смущает. И неужели при многочисленных братьях нельзя обособить этого Борьку? В моём примере мне хочется поставить запятую, потому что идёт размеренное повествование сказки, и пауза к месту, да и Розенталь не против. У автора (издателя, редактора, корректора) запятой нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Как известно,  при постановке знаков препинания соблюдаются **три принципа** – семантический, грамматический и интонационный. Первый принцип  определяет смысл сообщения, а два других его форму, то есть для конкретного содержания мы подбираем подходящую форму.

2) Посмотрим, как эти принципы действуют **при обособлении имени собственного, стоящего после приложения** (нарицательного существительного). Итак, мы должны выбрать нужный вариант из двух, например: сестра Маша или сестра, Маша.

**С точки зрения смысла,** обособленное имя собственное становится **уточняющим**. В этом случае мы или **делаем выбор** (к примеру, из трех сестер выбираем Машу), или просто сообщаем собеседнику **дополнительную информацию**, если о выборе вопрос не ставится (кстати, ее зовут Маша).

Здесь очень важна **коммуникативная ситуация**: с кем мы разговариваем, что он знает о нашей семье, поймет ли,  о ком идет речь и нужно ли это понимать, важно ли это.

**С точки зрения грамматики,**  при обособлении имени собственного подлежащим (или дополнением)  становится приложение, а имя собственное уходит на второй план. **С точки зрения интонации,**  приложение выделяется ударением, в то время как при отсутствии обособления его позиция была  бы безударной. Все эти факторы надо учитывать.

3) А теперь обратимся  к  «сыну Борьке» в предложении: ***Он сына моего, Борьку, напомнил.***

Это Борис Полевой, цикл рассказов «Современники».  Далее приводится цитата из рассказа. https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=202771&p=41

*Начальник стройки поднялся из-за стола, прошелся по комнате.*

*— Рассказать о какой-нибудь интересной, особо запомнившейся встрече?.. Так-так-так…
Собеседник произнес это задумчиво, как бы разговаривая сам с собой. 
Вдруг он резко отвернулся от окна:*

*— Хорошо. Я расскажу, пожалуй, один такой случай…
 …Так вот, произошло это в моем кабинете. Народу ко мне ходит много. И вот как-то, в начале лета, предстал передо мной какой-то молодой человек. … Пригляделся. Лицо крупное, некрасивое, но привлекательное — юношеской чистотой своей, что ли. **Очень он мне вдруг почему-то сына моего, Борьку, напомнил, который погиб где-то в этих краях в сорок втором году…***

**Здесь явно нет выбора**, собеседник собирается рассказать писателю об интересном человеке и **вскользь упоминает** о том, что при первой встрече он напомнил ему сына. Упоминает как бы для себя и имя тоже произносит для себя, чтобы вспомнить лишний раз погибшего сына. Так что **привет редакторам Розенталя**, которые решили посчитать количество сыновей в этой семье.

А когда всё-таки  **надо делать выбор** при обособлении, когда не следует вообще обособлять?  Из приведенных ниже примеров ясно видно, что всё зависит от ситуации (кто разговаривает, насколько собеседники понимают друг друга). Каждый раз это **авторское решение, чем-либо обоснованное.**

*Мне кажется, он похож на его сына,  Борьку.  Мне кажется, он похож на его сына Борьку.

В нашей школе учится  сын его Борька, а другой сын, Саша,  уже закончил школу.*

4) **И наконец, о Марфуше-царевне.** Имена большинства героев русских сказок  включают какое-либо **определение**: Василиса Премудрая, Марья Моревна, Марья-искусница, Елена Прекрасная. Если нет определения, то хотя бы Иван-царевич или Марфа-царевна. По Розенталю, в этом случае мы имеем одно **сложное интонационно-смысловое целое.**

***Этот царь ушёл с войсками, а цАрством осталась править //дочь его Марфа-царЕвна.***

Царских детей мы считать не будем: кто мог править, тот и остался.  Информацию с имени также не считываем: тот же Иван-царевич из этой сказки живет не у своего родного отца, а у другого царя.

**Почему нет обособления?** Марфа-царевна – главная   **героиня сказки**, важно, что именно она осталась править, а не то,  что она дочь царя. Здесь нарицательное существительное только определение для собственного имени. Так что семантика обособления не требует.

**А интонация**, почему хочется поставить запятую?  Просто вторая часть предложения значительна по объему, но **ее нужно правильно прочитать.**

При обособлении это выглядело бы так:

***Этот царь ушёл с войсками, а царством осталась править дОчь его, // Марфа-царЕвна.***

Такая интонация тоже возможна, но этот вариант не проходит по семантике.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И всё-таки (смеюсь уже) про Борьку и редакторов Розенталя: то есть независимо от количества братьев его можно и обособить, и не обособить, исходя из перечисленных Вами принципов (конечно, не в том конкретном примере из Полевого, а гипотетически) .

Comment: И еще попутно (хотя, может, это вопрос отдельный и не простой). Я правильно понимаю, что если имя стоит после нарицательного существительного и обособляется, то является приложением, а если не обособляется, то приложением оказывается это существительное?  Наверно, нет. У Вас в ответе, приложение всегда нарицательное. А у Розенталя говорится, что имя становится приложением. Ух.

Comment: 1) Однозначное решение может быть, но в особых случаях. Например, если мы рассказываем о разных сыновьях, как в приведенном примере: В нашей школе учится сын его Борька, а другой сын, Саша, уже закончил школу. В первом случае нельзя обособить, а во втором случае нельзя не обособить. Нужно правильно указывать признаки. 2) А обособленное  имя приходится называть обособленным приложением при определяемом нарицательном слове, нужно же как-то назвать его роль в предложении.

Comment: Примечание. А где же ваши ответы на вопросы, здесь есть парочка интересных (Н и НН и тире в неполных предложениях).

Comment: Я же ответил на два. Один большой, другой так - попутный. Мне же нужно время, чтоб самому разобраться и не накосячить :)

Comment: Ну ладно, отвечайте тогда на эти. Я пока не буду, мне интересно ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

"Марфа-царевна" может выступать здесь только как *уточнение*, вводящее (или ссылающееся на) альтернативу именования персонажа по имени Марфа, которая перед этим уже упомянута как "дочь царя" (= царевна) - соответственно, *нужна* запятая. Если бы вместо "Марфа-царевна" было просто "Марфа", то запятая возможна была бы только в случае намеренного указания на *единственную* дочь царя (без запятой нельзя сказать, есть ли другие).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Про Марфу-царевну понятно. А вот про Марфу всё равно не могу понять, так же как с Борькой из Розенталя. То есть если есть запятая, то точно единственная, а без запятой - то ли есть сёстры, то ли нет? Какие-то шахматы :)